# Помощь в написании запроса VK api android

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, android-sdk, android-vksdk

Пишу для учебных целей собственный клиент для ВК. В общем, у меня есть запрос, который выводит список друзей с ВК. 
Запрос:

```
VKRequest vkRequest = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name","order","hints"));
```

Вместо "first_name", что бы я ни писал, всё равно выводит только имя и фамилию. Помогите сделать так, чтобы выводилась еще ссылка на фото пользователя или само фото (в документации вк вроде пишет что только ссылка). Спасибо!

Comment: Неужели в документации ни слова про это? Что-то не верится

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю что такое ваш `VKRequest`, но самый обычный HTTP-запрос возвращает ровно то, что требуется:

> https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?count=1&user_id=1&fields=photo_50,photo_100,photo_200_orig

Приходит:

```
{"response":[
 {
  "uid":2,"first_name":"Александра","last_name":"Владимирова",
  "photo_50":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c837424\/v837424002\/7a58\/EXPtAjVvB3Y.jpg",
  "photo_100":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c837424\/v837424002\/7a57\/LPopmL-2n2M.jpg",
  "photo_200_orig":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c837424\/v837424002\/7a56\/moevLzq_O3k.jpg",
  "hidden":1,"user_id":2
 },
]}
```

Comment: Согласен, но я думаю что можно и через запросы к VK-SDK сделать. Я просто не знаю как правильно его написать. Я пробовал через кому прописать "photo_50", но ничего не происходит. Спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте делать запрос такого вида

```
final VKRequest vKRequest = new VKRequest("photos.search", VKParameters.from("start time", 1392005288, "end_time", 1479658261)
```

Где, соответственно "photos.search" - название метода который вам нужен.
"start time" - параметр передаваемый в метод.
1392005288 - значение данного параметра. Ну и так соответственно далее. Переделайте под себя и посмотрите, должно работать